# Centos Linux no longer has " System ---> Administration ---> Printing " after re-install from "Minimal" iso file

Tags: linux, centos, yum, repository

Recently i installed centos linux minimal and then
installed GUI over it.

i noticed it no longer has

```
System ---> Administration ---> Printing
```

given that this is not a 'software' how can i go about bringing this fuctionality back ? can it be done via "yum" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done via yum - I haven't had the need to do exactly this myself, but I'm relatively certain you can get that functionality back by doing a `yum groupinstall "Printing client"`. If that doesn't work, try `yum groupinstall "Print Server"`.